# Navbar bug on bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

So I made a navbar and now I want it show on it some after after I activate a javascript function.

The HTML code:

```
<ul id="HelloDiv" class="nav navbar-nav">
<li id="UserHello" style="visibility: hidden"><a href="#">Hello</a></li></ul>
```

The javascript code:

```
function IsLogedIn(TextBoxID) 
  {

      if(TextBoxID.value != 'nothing')
      {
         document.getElementById('LogInBTN').style.visibility = 'hidden';
         document.getElementById('UserHello').style.visibility = 'visible';
       // document.getElementById('HelloDiv').className = 'nav navbar-nav';
       // document.getElementById('UserHello').className = 'nav navbar-nav';
         document.getElementById('UserHello').innerHTML  = 'hello ' + TextBoxID.value; 

      } 
 }
```

[This is how it supposed to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqzCo.png)

[This is how it really look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7aHT.png)

Help?

Comment: do not post image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the set the class of UserHello element to `navbar-text`

```
<ul id="HelloDiv" class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="UserHello" class="navbar-text" style="visibility: hidden"><a href="#">Hello</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: NP! If this was the correct answer please be sure to mark it as such.

Answer (score 0):

I know how to help you with your question, but mainly because of the code and the links you supplied. If you could reword your question for future issues of this nature, it would be appreciated. Thanks.

The solution is to add a margin. This is to push to text downwards and to stop any elements crossing over it.

Hope this helps